# onSMSArrive cordova sms plugins executed more than once

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I was developing an app that have capability to read sms content when the user get sms.

So I use ionic and cordova sms plugin to read the sms content. But when user get a sms and triggered the onSMSArrive event provided by the plugin, it did work and can read the sms content.

The problem is it execute (read the sms) more then once, tree times to be exact.

I place this code as a service in ionic.

```
app.factory('$smsarrive', [function() {
    return {
        periksa:function() {

            if (SMS) SMS.enableIntercept(true, function() {
                    console.log("some debug hint here");
                }, function(){
                    console.log("some debug hint here");
                });

            if(SMS) SMS.startWatch(function() {
                //update('watching', 'watching started');
                    console.log("some debug hint here");
                }, function(){
                   //updateStatus('failed to start watching');
                   console.log("some debug hint here");
                });

            document.addEventListener('onSMSArrive', function(e) {
                var sms = e.data;
                var isiSms = sms.body;

                if (isiSms.match(/FC0019229/g)!=null) {
                    if (isiSms.match(/Berhasil/g)!=null) {
                        console.log("Isi pulsa Berhasil");
                    } else if (isiSms.match(/Gagal/g)) {
                        console.log("Isi pulsa Gagal");
                    } else {
                        console.log(isiSms);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("some hint here");
                }
                console.log("ASLI : "+isiSms);                       
            });
        }

    }
}])
```

and execute that service whenever a controller of a view is

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function() {
    $smsarrive.periksa();
})
```

Any suggestion? And also sorry for bad english.

i use [this plugin](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-sms)

Comment: Please provide a link to the specific plugin you're using.

Comment: @MikeM. thanks for the comment, i edited my question to provide the plugin url.

Comment: Yeah, that plugin doesn't quite handle incoming messages correctly. Does this happen with every message, or just long ones? How long is the message you're testing?

Comment: @MikeM. every single messages i received. even with three or two letters. i couldn't find any other sms plugins that offer capability to handle incoming messages. any recomendation? thanks again.

Comment: Hmm, not off the top of my head. I don't use Cordova, but I've looked through that plugin's Java source before, and I know it mishandles multipart messages, which causes it to fire once for each part. What happens when you receive a multipart message? That is, one longer than 160 characters in basic ASCII. Does it fire six times?

Comment: @MikeM. yeah, six time.

Comment: Well, at least that works as expected, though not as you want. Not sure what to tell ya, other than it sounds like you might be adding that event listener multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand in your code examples, you are executing the function "periksa" every time a view is entered ( that's what fires the '$ionicView.enter' event). Then also, you are creating an EventListener for SMS messages every time you execute 'periksa' (every time a view is entered).

So, if you have entered three views, you would have three listeners firing for the arrival of an SMS onSMSArrive.

So, I think you should only Start Watching, and add the EventListener, once, when starting the app (in app.js, inside .run, when $ionicPlatform.ready()).

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $smsarrive) {
   $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
   if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
     cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
     cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

   }
   if (window.StatusBar) {
    // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
    StatusBar.styleDefault();
   }

   if(( /(ipad|iphone|ipod|android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) )) {

     if (! SMS ) { alert( 'SMS plugin not ready' ); return; }

     SMS.startWatch(function(){
       console.log('Watching');
     }, function(){
       console.log('Not Watching');
     });

     document.addEventListener('onSMSArrive', function(e){
            var data = e.data;
            $smsarrive.periksa(data);
     });

   } else {
     alert('need run on mobile device for full functionalities.');
   }
});
```

Then, your 'periksa' function should only receive the data as a parameter, for processing and disposing of the results.

Let me know if this was helpful, i'm also studying this framework and I have this plugin working in my App.